# R recall variable name

Tags: r, variables

I'd like to create several tables in which my data are stored.
I did the follow:

```
x<-mydata
splitted<-split(x[,1],x[,2])

#Create my function for the tables
fxdata<-function(){
y.row=c("0","1","2","3","4","5")
yy=c(rep(0,6))
w=data.frame(A3=yy,A2=yy,A1=yy,A0=yy)
rownames(w)<-y.row}

#Create the tables
xx<-NULL
for (i in 1:dim(x)[2]){
assign(paste("xx",i,sep=""),fxdata())}
```

So, I created, for example, 3 tables: xx1, xx2 and xx3. Now I have to populate the tables and here I have the problem. I do not know how to recall xx1, xx2 or xx3 in a loop. The idea is insert the follow loop in the previous one, in order to populate all the tables.

```
 #Populate the table
 for (ii in 1:length(splitted[[1]]{
 #IF 0
 if (splitted[[1]][ii] == "0"){
 y[1,4]=y[1,4]+1}
 #IF A0
 if (splitted[[1]][ii] == "1A0"){
 y[2,4]=y[2,4]+1}
 if (splitted[[1]][ii] == "2A0"){
 y[3,4]=y[3,4]+1}
 if (splitted[[1]][ii] == "3A0"){
 y[4,4]=y[4,4]+1}
 ...}
```

The question is: what I have to write in place of "y" in the last loop in order to refer to xx1, xx2 or xx3?? I want to write something like:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
xxi<-1}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Marco

Comment: you could check at start of the loop if xxi are empty with `nrow(xxi)==0`, if TRUE, `assign('xxi', yourdata)` FALSE `assign('xxi',rbind(get('xxi),yourdata))`

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do and your code isn't reproducible. But I'm quite sure that you shouldn't need `assign` and `for` (only advanced R users have legitimate use cases for `assign`, for beginners it's just a sign of badly written code, usually they should just use a list).

Answer (score 0):

As Roland suggested, do something like this:

```
mydata<-list(xx1,xx2,xx3)
 for (j in names(mydata)) {
   mydata$j <- [your function stuff]
}
```

What you've written, btw, is much better implemented via `switch`